# App not installed error with the app already installed from playstore

Tags: android

I have the app installed from playstore and tried installing the release apk of same app in the device by increasing the version code .
App not installed error occuring . If i uninstall the already installed package its working fine but i need to update the existing package wat i have .

Comment: Have you updated the Version Code ?

Comment: Check your application id and key against old apk it must be same

Answer (score 0):

Its ok. Because you tries to install new release with different no. and package is  same. So , there is lots of conflict to directly install apk.

Comment: You need to uninstall old apk first then after install new one.

Comment: Its not about installing the new package but updating the old one

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

When you're ready to make changes to your APK, make sure to **update** your **app’s version code** as well so that existing users(existing app) will receive your update.

Version Code should be a whole number...